# Access VBA Filtering out multiple Criteria one a table mark complete on when all is Done

Tags: vba, ms-access

Have a table that has multiple Order Numbers and with those there is multiple Line Numbers. Basically There is a Order Number 123456 and there could be 5 Different Line Numbers with it. I want to be able to say when all those line numbers are complete then Mark the Order Number Complete. Thinking about using a recordset and a dcount. As you can see in the picture there are multiple Line Numbers with the same Order Number.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Saving calculated data, especially aggregate calc, is often not necessary and can even put data integrity at risk - saved calculated aggregate can get 'out of sync' with data. "Done" status can be calculated when needed. Domain aggregate function is one way. In a textbox or query:

`IIf(DCount("*", "OrderDetails", "ord_no='" & [ord_no] & "' AND doc_completed = False")=0, "Done", "Not Done")`

or

`Nz(DLookup("doc_completed", "OrderDetails, "ord_no='" & [ord_no] "' AND doc_completed = False"), "True")`

A correlated subquery should be able to return same value and possibly perform more efficiently.
`SELECT *, IIf((SELECT Count(*) FROM OrderDetails WHERE ord_no=Orders.OrderNumber AND doc_completed = False)=0, True, False) AS IsDone FROM Orders;`

Or build an aggregate query that counts records where doc_completed = False GROUP BY ord_no and join that query to Orders table.